# How can I change a label's text in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm really new to Swift but I have no idea why this isn't working, I'm trying to change the text of this label.

```
import SpriteKit
var counter:Int = 0
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        var myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Tahoma")
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;
        myLabel.name = "Button"
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        myLabel.text = String(counter);
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            counter++
            var lol = self.childNodeWithName("Button").text=counter
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: `myLabel.name = "NewText"` Where's the problem?

Comment: var lol = self.childNodeWithName("Button").text=counter <-- This part of the code I don't really know how to do it, it tells me 'SKNode does not have member named text'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do [type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

```
if let label = self.childNodeWithName("Button") as? SKLabelNode {
   label.text = counter
}
```